No such module 'CCUDD'
I am running a swift project in VSCode. I am trying to import a package from another git repository, but somehow it is not being recognized.
I think I have the dependencies right, but given that I am new to swift, I am not too sure.
My Package.swift is the following:
// swift-tools-version: 5.10
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CUDD",
    products: [ .library(name: "CUDD", targets: ["CUDD"]),],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/danielaisen/CCUDD.git", from: "1.1.0")
    ],
    targets: [        
        .target(
            name: "CUDD", 
            dependencies: ["CCUDD"],
            path: "Sources"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CUDDTests", 
            dependencies: ["CUDD"])]
)


When I try to
import CCUDD

I get the following error as mentioned: "no such module 'CCUDD'sourcekitd"
I do not think it matter. but I run on Ubuntu 22.04. VScode. swift 5.10.
tried to rename the dependency.
modify the release.
The CCUDD package.swift is the following:
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package: Package  = Package(
    name: "CCUDD",
        products: [ .library(name: "CCUDD", targets: ["CCUDD"]),],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CCUDD", 
            dependencies: [], 
            path: "Sources"),
    ]
)


I haven't used swift on linux so I don't really know what the issue is but I wanted to point out that in your .testTarget the target that you are testing should be listed under dependencies so I suppose it should be dependencies: ["CUDD"]. Any other dependencies should only be included if you need them for writing the actual test code.

Hi @JoakimDanielson thx. yes agree the dependency should be "CUDD", instead of "CCUDD", and it it in the main branch. it was one of the things I tried to modify to see if magically it will fix the issue..
